# Kubernetes Run multiple python script in Same Pod

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have 4-5 Python scripts which are consumers/producers for Kafka and need to run till the end of time.

I can create container for each single script but then I will have 4-5 containers and Kubernetes will manage it if anything fails.

But I want to run all these in a Single Pod and if any of the script fails then that script should only be started and not the whole pod which in turn will start all the current transactions happening in perfectly running scripts.

Is there a way we can achieve it?
Or what will be the best possible solution - Run individually in each container or run them in single container.

If in future more scripts come in then what can I do to achieve the desired behavior.

**REASON** in movig script in 1 pod - 1 script ~ 1 container ~ 400 MB.
Now 5 script ~ 5 container ~ 2 GB.

Comment: why would you want all of them in the same Pod?

Comment: i container is 400 MB, then 5 different containers will be 2 GB

Comment: The memory usage should be pretty much identical whether you're running 5 processes in 1 container, 5 containers in 1 pod, or 5 separate pods.  If all of the pods use the same image, you'll only pay the disk space cost once per node.  You need to run one script per pod to get the restart behavior you want.

Comment: What if i want to scale the consumers, script count increases to 10, then 10 different containers?? And what about overhead of same base image, same dependencies in all the containers??

Answer (score 1):

This is not a suggested pattern! One process per container is the suggested one!

Running all the scripts in the same container will use the same amount of RAM more or less (~2GB) overhead of containers is very less.

You can run all 5 of the scripts using some init process like s6 https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay and s6 will take care of only starting the stopped script

Comment: What happens if I want to scale up my consumers to 10 then 10 different containers and additionally all 10 containers are repititive - same base image, same dependencies and a single script to run.

Comment: It's will be slightly on the storage but not on the RAM